# how to identify obejct level access for role & user in DB2

Tags: db2, role

I have created a role in DB2 and granted some object level access to that role and next ranted that role to some users. How Can I identify which user is having this role and due to that what access the user is having object level.

Answer (score 0):

The DB2 function [AUTH_LIST_AUTHORITIES_FOR_AUTHID](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0052898.html) probably is what you are looking for. In the background it queries the [system catalog tables](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0011297.html) for entries of that specified user. If you are only looking for certain object types, you could directly query a single catalog table, e.g., [SYSCAT.TABAUTH](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001061.html) for who has access to tables. There is a column for GRANTEETYPE and a value to indicate "role".

You can find users and their roles by querying [SYSCAT.ROLEAUTH](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0050619.html).

Comment: Actually I am looking for a query which will give what are role owned by any user and at the same time what are the object level privileges are there for that role

Comment: I added SYSCAT.ROLEAUTH to the list of catalog tables. That table would be the one to query (select ... from syscat.roleauth where grantee='userIDinQuestion')

Comment: I am looking for a output which will give : username, rolename, objectname, objecttype,accesslevel,grantee etc. if in case the user doesn't have access to any role, but only have access to any specific objects then rolename should be null of that query output

Answer (score 0):

you can use db2look tool to extract the information regarding all the access that particular role carrying or what access is being carrying by the user...

db2look -d database_name -x -o db2look.out